# List users that have access to app in azure ad

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

In our azure ad portal, we have multiple apps and not all users have access to all apps. In my current application, I have to list all users that have access to this application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my current application

If you mean the AD app, you cannot list all user that have access to your app; If you mean web app, you could use **Access control (IAM)** in the portal to get the user list. Or you can use REST API to get it. For the details about REST API, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. by application, i am refering to a web app that is registered in the azure ad. Not all users that have been registered in the azure ad would be accessing this web application, and I would like to only list the users that have been assigned to the desired web application. I am not sure, if this is already answered in your reply, but i was unable to find a solution

Comment: Have you tried REST API? If you tried this, you can get the pincipalid, and then you use [get-user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/users/get) to get user list that assigned to the app.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that and it worked for me. Thanks alot